# Windows Performance Monitor: where is it?

Tags: windows-xp, performance-monitor

Where is the Performance Monitor in Windows XP? How can it be started using the Windows menus?

I can start it from the Run dialog:

```
perfmon.exe
```

But I am sure there is GUI way to start it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows XP Performance Monitor can started by: Start menu/Settings/Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Performance

Answer (score 2):

That's hard-wired into my brain: Win+R "perfmon.msc"  (and it generally requires only "per" once it's in the Run history)

The actual snap-in itself though lives at C:\WINDOWS\system32\perfmon.msc, so it's easy enough to right-click and Create Shortcut, then put that shortcut anywhere that fits your fancy.  (I keep mind in the Quick Launch toolbar.)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it is a part of the Microsoft Management Console (right click "My Computer" and select "Administer"). Apart from that, it is no where else. Just a stand alone application.