# Windows 7 style perfomance monitor for windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, performance-monitor

Is there a free downloadable utility that will show me memory, disc, processor and network usage on Windows XP as neatly and intuitively as the Windows 7 Perfmon?

Comment: What's wrong with Windows XP Performance Monitor? (http://superuser.com/questions/36463/windows-performance-monitor-where-is-it)

Comment: its ugly and hard to read (in my opinion). The Win7 version is big improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from the MS Sysinternals package can show you just about everything that is going on with your computer.  I use it any time I need to figure out why things are running slow or what is eating all my memory.  It can be configured to show graphs, etc.