# Does making hundreds of Google Drive files available offline slow down my computer?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, performance, google-chrome-extensions, web-application

I collaborate on many Google documents: Docs, Sheets, Slides. I've made hundreds of them available offline (File → Make available offline). What are the performance implications of doing so?

I am not worried about the space that these available-offline documents are consuming on my SSD. I am instead worried that Google is constantly syncing these documents, and that making hundreds of them available offline is hampering my computer's performance.

I looked for answers to this question here and on webapps.stackexchange.com, but I didn't find any posts that speak directly to the matter.

**Addendum**

I'm using Windows 10 Pro. I use Windows' built-in Task Manager to monitor CPU usage. (Sometimes I also use Chrome's built-in task manager.)

Comment: There are too many variables to know if **your** computer, **your** internet access speed, etc. are slowed  by Google Drive Sync. Nor would that help others who might ask that. However, **you** could easily test that by turning  off Google Sync: https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/stop-google-drive-sync-1234.html . Does it make a difference?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, your point is well taken. But I don't use Google Sync; I access Google Drive only through my browser, and not through any standalone app.

Comment: Here on Super Users, there isn't a tag for the web app of Google Drive as web applications are off-topic, however, a question like this might need it as the "Make available off-line" feature is only available when using Google Chrome. What operative system are you using? What are you doing to track your computer performance and the sync task resource usage?

Comment: @Wicket, thank you. To answer your questions: I'm using Windows 10 Pro. I use Windows' built-in Task Manager to monitor CPU usage. (Sometimes I also use Chrome's built-in task manager.)

Answer (score 2):

The details about how [Work on Google Docs, Sheets, & Slides offline](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102?hl=en) affect computer performance have not been disclosed by Google.

An old article posted by Google explained that Google files are stored as small data chunks that might be distributed across multiple data centers and storage devices. They are put together when the user opens them in their browser this process of putting the data together implies converting it into file formats that the web browser might render.

As Google file formats have a version history highlighting the edit parts, the sync process may only download the complete files on the initial download into the user's computer. After that, only the edited parts may be synced. Theoretically, this should have a negligible impact on the user's computer, but there have been user reports about Chrome affecting the computer's performance, but it is constantly being updated.

As there are several factors that might affect a computer's performance you should learn to use the Windows features to track the computer's performance.

Resources

- [Configure Performance Monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/configure-performance-monitoring)

Related

- [Windows Performance Monitor: where is it?](https://superuser.com/q/36463/1794161)
- [What is Performance Monitor telling me when my page faults / second are high?](https://superuser.com/q/240578/1794161)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, that should not affect your computer's performance. But if your files are large in size and are often updated by users, then GoogleDrive app can create some heavy traffic and slow down the network, which may affect your browsing experience and some other network related things. But most likely you won't notice that impact unless you have slow connection. But if you do, then in order to address this you can go to GoogleDrive **Settings** (**Preferences**) and look for **"Bandwidth settings"** section. There you can limit the **download** and **upload** rates, so the GoogleDrive won't use all available bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't use the standalone Google Drive app—I use Google Drive exclusively through my browser. In turn, I don't have a Google-Drive-specific option to change bandwidth settings.

Comment: Are you using Google Docs Offline Chrome extension? Anyways, the answer is the same. On a solid network connection you'll have smooth experience.